# How would I scrape a Google Map link to get info about Resturant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, web-scraping, nokogiri, rails-activestorage

I am trying to write a method in my controller to get basic info about a Resturant, given the google maps link, and make a Resturant Object. And if possible I would like to grab the images too. I am using Active Storage for images. Here a list of what I want to scrape:

- Name
- Address
- Phone
- Website
- Cuisine
- Price Range (Number of $s)
- Rating (Number of stars)
- Hours

So far I have tried to just get the name and can't get it to work. Heres my method:

```
def scrape_google
    google_link = params[:google_link]
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(google_link))
  
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
    
    #Returant Name
    restaurant_name_element = page.at_css('h1.DUwDvf.fontHeadlineLarge')
    @restaurant.name = restaurant_name_element&.text&.strip if restaurant_name_element
    
  
    # Output scraped information to the console
    puts "Scraped Information:"
    puts "Name: #{@restaurant&.name}"
    
  
    render :scrape_google
  end
```

Comment: "can't get it to work" is not useful information -- add to the question the results or errors that occur when you execute your code.

Comment: The console doesn't show that any information was pulled. Next to "Name: " it's just blank.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is against the google maps terms of service.  The right way to do the kind of things you're talking about are easily available:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service